# Cannot install Jekyll on Manjaro

Tags: jekyll, manjaro

On a fresh **Manjaro** install, after having installed the **Ruby** with
`pacman -S ruby`
I tried to install **Jekyll** running

```
gem install bundler jekyll
```

The bundler has been installed successfully, but the Jekyll installation gave me this error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/jgabrielgruber/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/ext/ffi_c
/usr/bin/ruby -I /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0 -r ./siteconf20220428-5815-4q66ic.rb extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... yes
checking for ffi_prep_closure_loc() in -lffi... yes
checking for ffi_prep_cif_var()... yes
checking for ffi_raw_call()... yes
checking for ffi_prep_raw_closure()... yes
checking for whether -pthread is accepted as LDFLAGS... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

current directory: /home/jgabrielgruber/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/ext/ffi_c
make DESTDIR\= clean
current directory: /home/jgabrielgruber/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/ext/ffi_c
make DESTDIR\=
make failedNo such file or directory - make
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, on the

> make failedNo such file or directory - make

It says that the **make** command is not installed on Manjaro, to solve this, you need to install it with:

```
pacman -S make
```